# Navbar when clicked is not redirecting to another page bootstrap 5

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

The issue is that when I click the navbar item it's not redirecting to the page and not giving any feedback. But when I delete the `bootstrap.bundle.min.js` it's working as it should be, but the expand button for the navbar when it's collapsed is not working.

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-+0n0xVW2eSR5OomGNYDnhzAbDsOXxcvSN1TPprVMTNDbiYZCxYbOOl7+AMvyTG2x" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        .nav{
            margin-bottom: 0px !important; 
            margin-top: 0px !important;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <!--Heading Navbar-->
    <header class="border-bottom site-header sticky-top bg-white">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-light navbar-expand-lg bg-white">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="d-flex flex-grow-1">
                <a href="#" class="navbar-brand col-md-3 bg-white">
                    <img src="logo.jpg" class="img-fluid">
                </a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navNavbar" aria-controls="navNavbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse flex-grow-1 text-right" id="navNavbar" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target=".navbar-collapse.show">
                <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto flex-nowrap">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link px-2 m-2 link-dark" href="index.html">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link px-2 m-2 link-secondary" href="about.html">About</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link px-2 m-2 link-secondary" href="products.html">Products</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link px-2 m-2 link-secondary" href="contactus.html" >Contact Us</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <!--Content-->
    <!--Necessary Scripts-->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-gtEjrD/SeCtmISkJkNUaaKMoLD0//ElJ19smozuHV6z3Iehds+3Ulb9Bn9Plx0x4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the `data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target=".navbar-collapse.show"` on the `navbar-collapse` div. Remove it and the navigation will work fine.

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse flex-grow-1 text-right" id="navNavbar" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target=".navbar-collapse.show">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto flex-nowrap">
             ...
      </ul>
</div>
```

[Demo](https://codeply.com/p/a7E975d6Ef)

Also, jQuery is not required for Bootstrap 5